# Blank Page PHP Error from Old CogeIgniter Library

Tags: php, codeigniter, deprecated

I downloaded an open source PHP invoicing program (Bamboo) about two years ago and used it for a few quick invoices that I needed to send.

Now when I try to access the home page, it is blank.  I looked in my log file and it reads "exit signal Segmentation fault".

I then attempted to force the php variable within the URL, so I typed 'http://localhost/bamboo/index.php?/login' and this actually returned to me a page with errors, namely a deprecated function in the CodeIgniter Code.

I've never had experience with CodeIgniter, and I'm assuming that I need to upgrade it to fix these errors, however it doesn't look as easy as I thought judging from their update page.

Can anyone give me advice on how I can break through this error to access my old invoices?  FYI, it looks like the current CodeIgniter version I have is 1.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a WAMP / LAMP test environment running an old version of PHP (~4 or pre 5.3) then test it that way, it should work under old environment, it will be the fastest as if it worked before, it will work with old dependencies.

Comment: I have XAMPP setup now with my Mac - is it possible to run two versions of PHP with the same installation?

Comment: I don't know of a good way without you running it on a non standard port like say port 81 will be your old 4.3 install.

Comment: Try this: http://gggeek.altervista.org/2007/07/21/running-multiple-php-versions-on-a-single-apache-install/